# Cordova trigger offline network event for wifi only

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I installed the plugin cordova-plugin-network-information
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/8.x/reference/cordova-plugin-network-information/

it contains an event called "offline". This event triggers fine, but my problem is that it only seems to trigger based on the initial connection that was available at the time of my apps initiation.

For example:

User is on 4G and also has local WiFI connection. I only want the offline to trigger if the WiFi is offline. Currently, it will only trigger if I disable the 4G.

The only way I can get the offline event to fire for the WiFi is if I have the device completely already starting with 4G turned off and WiFi is the only interface on.

Anyone have any ideas on the best way to only monitor wifi offline event?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [plugin's documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information#network-related-events):

> The offline event fires when a previously connected device loses a
>   network connection so that an application can no longer access the
>   Internet. It relies on the same information as the Connection API, and
>   fires when the value of connection.type becomes NONE.

This means that it will be triggered when **both WiFi and data connections become unavailable**, and you can't change that behavior. You could probably fork the plugin and edit it to suit your needs, but it would take a lot of work and your plugin won't get any further updates.

Comment: Yep makes sense. I already did my own workaround for my needs, but I totally understand. Thanks for info.